# Nullable types and the ternary operator: why is `? 10 : null` forbidden?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, conditional-operator

I just came across a weird error:

```
private bool GetBoolValue()
{
    //Do some logic and return true or false
}
```

Then, in another method, something like this:

```
int? x = GetBoolValue() ? 10 : null;
```

Simple, if the method returns true, assign 10 to the Nullable`int` x. Otherwise, assign null to the **nullable** int. However, the compiler complains:

> Error 1   Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `int` and `<null>`.

Am I going nuts?

Comment: See Stack Overflow question *[Why doesn't this C# code compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828950/why-doesnt-this-c-code-compile)*.

Comment: Maybe this will be corrected in a future version of the compiler because, there really is an implicit conversion between 'int' and '<null>' and that's 'int?'

Comment: @bruno, How is that different to saying "there really is an implicit conversion between [any type] and [any other type] and that's 'object'"? Do you think they'll "correct" that in a future version of the compiler too? For example: object x = GetBoolValue() ? (object)"foo" : (object)DateTime.Now;

Comment: Imagine the compiler was smart enough to say "OK, we're not using the first type (int), so we'll look for another type that we can use for the result of this expression."  What would you get if you typed "Console.WriteLine((Predicate() ? 5.6 : null).GetType().ToString());"?  Would you get float? or double? or object?  Or a user-defined class with implicit conversion from float?  How would the compiler know which type to pick, since it can't pick the one in the expression?

Comment: I mean, the bottom line is that there's nothing really special about nullable types except that they have a shorthand "?" syntax.  The compiler doesn't have a special flag telling it that an int? is "just like an int with a little bit extra, so try to use it when you can instead."

Comment: @Luke, I don't really understand you comment.

Comment: @mquander, It would print: System.Nullable`1[System.Single]

Comment: I don't understand Luke's comment either -- the code he's quoted makes sense and would compile right now as it stands, since he's explicitly cast each thing to object.

Comment: @bruno: My point is that 5.6 is a Single by default (or maybe a double, I forget; let's say it's a single.)  But that expression can't return a Single, since it could return null.  So somehow, the compiler has to figure out that Nullable<Single> is the right type to use, based on the fact that the original was a Single.  That sounds simple, but it's really not, because Nullable<T> is just another interface to the compiler, and doesn't have some special C# magic connecting it to the original type.  It wouldn't know that Nullable<Single> was a better choice than Nullable<double> or even object.

Comment: I'm beginning to see my confusion... Thanks for all your feedback :)

Comment: @bruno, @mquander, My point was meant to demonstrate that if you "correct" the compiler so that it infers that (test ? 10 : null) should be of type int? then wouldn't that also allow it to infer that (test ? "foo" : DateTime.Now) should be of type object because both operands can be converted to object.

Comment: @Luke, I understand your point know and I agree entirely. Thanks.

Comment: @bruno, @mquander, I'd personally prefer to see an error when I do something crazy like that, and if I really want an object then I'll do an explicit cast. The current behaviour of the compiler is fine: If there's an implicit conversion between the two types (not via a third guessed/inferred type) then everything works. If there isn't an implicit conversion then you'll get an error.

Comment: Indeed, one of the subtle but important design principles used throughout C# is that when deciding what type something is based on several alternatives, we always pick _the unique best of the alternatives_. We never "magic up" a new type that is not among the alternatives and then choose it. We only choose from types that are already in your code, and only if one of them is clearly better than the rest.

Comment: I have the benefit of being ten years in the future, but there's nothing "magic" about seeing the expression `someBool ? 5 : null` and deducing a type of `int?`. You still get an error if you try to assign that to a variable declared `int`. This idiosyncrasy makes sense in terms of the type system if you think of `Nullable<int>` as "just some struct", but it spoils the abstraction of nullable value types. We shouldn't be asked to think of `int`s and `null` as having mutually exclusive types any more than we should be asked to think of `string`s and `null` as having mutually exclusive types.

Answer (score 441, accepted):

The compiler first tries to evaluate the right-hand expression:

```
GetBoolValue() ? 10 : null
```

The `10` is an `int` literal (not `int?`) and `null` is, well, `null`. There's no implicit conversion between those two hence the error message.

If you change the right-hand expression to one of the following then it compiles because there is an implicit conversion between `int?` and `null` (#1) and between `int` and `int?` (#2, #3).

```
GetBoolValue() ? (int?)10 : null    // #1
GetBoolValue() ? 10 : (int?)null    // #2
GetBoolValue() ? 10 : default(int?) // #3
```

Comment: You can also write `new int?()`.

Comment: Or even better IMHO: `default(int?)`

Comment: Yes, the compiler requires this clue before it will **wrap** the `int` 10 to an `int?`. Note that another possibility would be to **box** the `int` 10 to a base class or interface of `System.Int32`. As an example `GetBoolValue() ? (IFormattable)10 : null // #1B` or `GetBoolValue() ? 10 : (IFormattable)null // #2B` will be OK. This possibility may be a reason why they don't make the nullable-wrapping automatic. Because both wrapping and boxing are normally _implicit_ conversions. That is both `int? variable = 10;` and `IFormattable variable = 10;` are legal (the former wraps, the latter boxes).

Comment: I hope my comment is within the context. My requirement was to pass null to an Oracle table number column, when a string is NULL. Against the example above, I managed it like this: cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OracleDbType.Double).Value = String.IsNullOrEmpty(pNumberChar) ? (Double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(pNumberChar);

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
int? x = GetBoolValue() ? 10 : (int?)null;
```

Basically what is happening is that conditional operator is unable to determine the "return type" of the expression.  Since the compiler implictitly decides that `10` is an `int` it then  decides that the return type of this expression shall be an `int` as well.  Since an `int` cannot be `null` (the third operand of the conditional operator) it complains.

By casting the `null` to a `Nullable<int>` we are telling the compiler explicitly that the return type of this expression shall be a `Nullable<int>`.  You could have just as easily casted the `10` to `int?` as well and had the same effect.

Comment: I know I can work around it, I'm just curious as to why this is happening?

Comment: You can shorten it further: `int? x = GetBoolValue() ? 10 : default;`

Answer (score 15):

Incidentally, the Microsoft implementation of the C# compiler actually gets the type analysis of the conditional operator wrong in a very subtle and interesting (to me) way. My article on it is *[Type inference woes, part one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/type-inference-woes-part-onex)* (2006-05-24).

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

`int? result = condition ? 10 : default(int?);`

Answer (score 5):

Try one of these:

```
int? x = GetBoolValue() ? (int?)10 : null;

int? x = GetBoolValue() ? 10 : (int?)null;
```

Comment: we can add another one:
int? x = GetBoolValue() ? 10 : new int?();

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the ternary operator is inferring type based on your first parameter assignment...10 in this case, which is an int, not a nullable int.

You might have better luck with:

```
int? x = GetBoolValue() (int?)10 : null;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int? x = GetBoolValue() ? 10 : (int?)null;
```

The reason you see this is because behind the scenes you're using Nullable and you need to tell C# that your "null" is a null instance of Nullable.

Comment: Doh! Andrew got their first. +1 to him.

Answer (score 4):

Just add an explict cast.

```
int? x = GetBoolValue() ? 10 : (int?)null;
```

It is the ternary operator that gets confused - the second argument is an integer and so is the third argument exspected to be an integer, too, and null does not fit.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the compiler determines the type of the conditional operator by its second and third operand, not by what you assign the result to. There is no direct cast between an integer and an null reference that the compiler can use to determine the type.

Comment: I disagree.  The natural expectation, I think, is that the type of the conditional expression would be the lowest common denominator of the types of the second and third operands.  The data type you're assigning the result into doesn't need to play any part in the type resolution.