# Conditional operator cannot cast implicitly?

Tags: c#, types, conditional-operator, implicit-conversion

I'm a little stumped by this little C# quirk:

Given variables:

```
Boolean aBoolValue;
Byte aByteValue;
```

The following compiles:

```
if (aBoolValue) 
    aByteValue = 1; 
else 
    aByteValue = 0;
```

But this will not:

```
aByteValue = aBoolValue ? 1 : 0;
```

Error says: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'."

And of course, this monstrosity will compile:

```
aByteValue = aBoolValue ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
```

What's going on here?

EDIT:

Using VS2008, C# 3.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nullable types and the ternary operator: why is \`? 10 : null\` forbidden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is a fairly frequently asked question.

In C#, we almost always reason from inside to outside. When you see

```
x = y;
```

we work out what is the type of x, what is the type of y, and whether the type of y is assignment compatible with x. But we do not use the fact that we know what the type of x is when we are working out the type of y.

That's because there might be more than one x:

```
void M(int x) { }
void M(string x) { }
...
M(y); // y is assigned to either int x or string x depending on the type of y
```

We *need* to be able to work out the type of an expression *without* knowing what it is being assigned to. Type information flows *out* of an expression, not *into* an expression.

To work out the type of the conditional expression, we work out the type of the consequence and the alternative expressions, pick the more general of the two types, and that becomes the type of the conditional expression. So in your example, the type of the conditional expression is "int", and it is not a constant (unless the condition expression is constant true or constant false). Since it is not a constant, you can't assign it to byte; the compiler reasons solely from the types, not from the values, when the result is not a constant.

The exception to all these rules is lambda expressions, where type information *does* flow from the context into the lambda. Getting that logic right was very difficult.

Comment: My mind is blown. Thank you, sir, that is one part enlightening and two parts frustrating. One because it can't work the way it would *seem* to work, and two because it makes sense that it can't work that way. So... constants it is!

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a post on this topic on your blog, but this is even better.

Comment: @John: I talk about these issues a bit here: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx

Comment: @Eric Lippert, I attempted to comment on your blog entry, but I'm not sure it took, so I'll ask here: Rather than attempt to resolve the types indepdently, why doesn't the compiler just convert the entire ternary expression into the equivalent "verbose expression" (in this case, `byte aByteValue; if (aBoolValue) aByteValue = 1; else aByteValue = 0;`)? Is there some gotcha that would make this not viable? Or is it a philosophical thing (e.g., "If it looks like an expression, it should be evaluated like one.")? I think most programmers would initially expect ternary to work exactly like if-else.

Comment: `var x = y` is different from `int x = y` and should be treated differently. In the first case I ask the compiler to figure this out, in the latter I tell it what I expect. And, as @devuxer says, most developers expect `?:` to work like `if-else`.

Comment: As of 2021 Eric's article can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/type-inference-woes-part-one

Answer (score 12):

I'm using VS 2005, for and I can reproduce, for bool & Boolean, but not for true

```
 bool abool = true;
 Boolean aboolean = true;
 Byte by1 = (abool ? 1 : 2);    //Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'
 Byte by2 = (aboolean ? 1 : 2); //Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'
 Byte by3 = (true ? 1 : 2);     //Warning: unreachable code ;)
```

The simplest workaround seems to be this cast

```
 Byte by1 = (Byte)(aboolean ? 1 : 2);
```

So, yes, it seems that the ternary operator is causing the constants to "fix" their types as ints and disable the implicit type conversion that you would otherwise get from constants that fit within the smaller type.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. But why would the constants not fix in this circumstance? And doubly curious with Mendy's discovery. Someone at Microsoft should know, and might need to be argued with strongly...

Comment: I think Mendy discovered that when compiler can trivially detect that it can optimize the ternary operator away entirely, it the compiles code that is equal to `Byte by = 2` which preserves the ability to implicitly cast. (see my comment on the compiler warning above)

Comment: I think Eric Lippert may have discussed the why of this already on his blog.

Comment: @John Knoeller: can you find link?

Comment: Heres a related link to his blog.  http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx
I havn't found the exact link, and I may have mis-remembered where I read about implicit casts anyway.

Comment: @Mendy: Found it http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 7):

I may not have a great answer for you, but if you do this in many places, you could declare:

```
private static readonly Byte valueZero = (byte)0;
private static readonly Byte valueOne = (byte)1;
```

and just these variables. You might get away with using `const` if it is local to the project.

***EDIT:*** using `readonly` would not make sense - these aren't ever meant to change.

Comment: I'm sure it was just a typo but you declared the same variable twice.

Comment: @Hamish: I see what you mean. I could use const, but it's a workaround. This certainly doesn't deserve the vote down you got though.