# C# tertiary if operator giving issue with nullable double

Tags: c#, if-statement, operators, nullable

I have a nullable double

```
MyNullableDouble = MyDouble == 0 ? null : MyDouble;
```

This is causing me an issue :

> *Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '' and 'double'*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should cast `Mydouble`, otherwise on the left side you have type `double?` while in the right part you have `double`, so types are not equivalent (and that's exactly what the exception is saying):

```
MyNullableDouble = MyDouble == 0 ? null : (double?)MyDouble;
```

Comment: Yes because double can be implicitly casted to nullableDouble, but the tertiary operator works in a different manner, there are lot of questions about this: see [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155618/implicit-conversion-issue-in-a-ternary-condition) for example, and follow the various duplicated questions

Comment: ok sorry I would have searched but I didnt know at the time it would be that kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

yes,you cannot do like this ,both the value should be of same data type.Any specific reason to use tertiary..use if else ...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a generic approach to handle such situations.
Since all Nullable types have `GetValueOrDefault` method, you can write an opposite method for non-Nullable structures:

```
    public static T? GetNullIfDefault<T>(this T value)
        where T: struct
    {
        if( value.Equals(default(T)))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
MyNullableDouble = MyDouble.GetNullIfDefault();
```