# How to fix 'Type of conditional expression cannot be determined'

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error:

[image]

*Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion 
between 'Car' and 'Bike'*

```cs
public interface IVehicle
{
    int Wheels { get; }
}

public class Car : IVehicle
{
    public int Wheels => 4;
}

public class Bike : IVehicle
{
    public int Wheels => 2;
}

public Garage()
{
    var licenseHeld = false;
    IVehicle vehicle = licenseHeld ? new Car() : new Bike();
}
```

Why cannot this conversion be done when both Car and Bike implement the same interface?

Comment: you need to cast at least of of the two to the interface

Comment: here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104861/6527049

Answer (score 1):

The type of consequent and alternative must be the same, or there must be an implicit conversion from one type to the other.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator