# Conditional operator in C# and return types

Tags: c#, sql, types, type-conversion, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why does null need an explicit type cast here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608878/why-does-null-need-an-explicit-type-cast-here)
>   [Nullable types and the ternary operator. Why won't this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work)

Attempting to do the following:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@DateCreated", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value 
    = myObject.DateCreated == DateTime.MinValue 
    ? DBNull.Value : myObject.DateCreated;
```

I am getting this error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot
>   be determined because there is no
>   implicit conversion between
>   'System.DBNull' and 'System.DateTime'

I obviously understand the error but why does type even matter given that Parameters.Value is of type object? Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Very much related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608878 - in fact, I consider them duplicates, since they have the exact same answer.  In short:  just cast one of them to an `Object`

Comment: This is a duplicate of several dozen questions. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080 and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450866 and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference that the return value is going into something that is an `object`, because *the type of the return value has to be determined first*.

Cast one of the two values (`DBNull.Value`, `myObject.DateCreated`) to a base of the other and you 'll be fine. In this case, the base can even be `object`.

Comment: Cheers, didn't think of doing the cast in the operator itself. Silly in retrospect.

Comment: But why is that? Each expression determines their own type, but only one is evaluated at runtime. As a programmer, I only care if the result is assignable to my variable. It would be nice if it could infer the type when I use `var`, but all the time base types aren't even considered, it will do a lousy job doing that and I have to add that ugly cast anyway.

Comment: @ThomasEyde: Not sure I understand, but it doesn't matter what is evaluated at runtime; the compiler has to figure out a single type for the value of the expression at compile time.

Comment: @Jon: If I write `object o = b ? new A() : new B()` there is nothing for the compiler to figure out except for: Are both expressions assignable to `o`? The fact that there are no relations between A and B is irrelevant. Everything the compiler needs to make this work is already there.

Comment: @ThomasEyde: I see. Well, off the top that's opening a can of worms. Say classes A : I1, I2 and B : I1, I2. What's the type of `b ? new A() : new B()`? What if the ternary is fed into a `var`? What if both classes have implicit conversion operators to C? Sure the compiler could really try to accommodate you and succeed some of the time, but a) probably can't justify a feature that only works some of the time and for which a trivial workaround is already available and b) introduces a factor of "let me guess what you really want" which is against the spirit of the language.

Comment: @Jon, ok, I see why inferring types from bases can be a problem. But that applies only when I assign the result to a `var`. In all other cases the assigned type is known. I can't see this as anything but an oversight when the spec was written.

Comment: @ThomasEyde: It applies everywhere where the type of the expression matters -- method call binding (including overload resolution) is the other obvious example and its reach is potentially enormous. This type of feature has a tendency to reveal more and more awkward cases the longer you think about it. Give the team some credit, in contrast to us they are well paid to think about this stuff. If someone has made an oversight odds are it's not them.

Comment: I have been reading explanation other places in the mean time, and the reason why things are the way they are seem to be a desire to support as many use cases as possible, however ugly or unlikely they are. I disagree, but what can I do? When it comes to give the team credit, I think they do a great job. But they are still human. Someone actually thought `if (myEvent != null) myEvent(new MyEventArgument())` was a good idea, while totally ignoring what pub-sub is all about.