# Bool? not nullable

Tags: c#, intellisense

I have following field in my class:

```
public bool? EitherObject1OrObject2Exists => ((Object1 != null || Object2 != null) && !(Object1 != null && Object2 != null)) ? true : null;
```

But in Visual Studio I get an IntelliSense error that there cannot be a conversion between "bool" and "NULL" even though the field is nullable.
What do I do wrong?
And is there a cleaner way to check if either one of two objects is not null but one of them must be null?

Comment: I think you might benefit from reading [Is Your Code Hard to Understand?](http://www.daedtech.com/code-hard-understand/) blog post by Erik Dietrich.

Comment: your expression is redundant. not saying this will solve the problem but its redundant.

Comment: @Os. Why is it redundant? Please explain

Comment: Your method simplifies down to just `Object1 != null ^ Object2 != null`

Comment: @Palmi Servy has already explained it.

Comment: This question has been asked probably several hundred times on this site.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3151584/88656 which contains links to articles I've written about this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
? (bool?) true : null;
```

the problem is that default `bool` (true) is not nullable so the case statement are returning different types as far as the compiler is concerned

And you can remove the redundancy as pointed out by Servy

```
Object1 != null ^ Object2 != null
```

Comment: I know its outside the scope of OP's question, but maybe include a fix for the redundant null check in their expression?

Comment: @maccettura done :)

Comment: I use bool? so I can use the [Required] data annotation

Comment: @Palmi make sense