# C# Nullable in conditional statement

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, nullable

Why do we need explicit cast in second statement?

`bool? a = null;
bool b = false;
bool c = true;`

1.)
`if(b || c)
 a = b;
else
 a = null;`

2.) `a = (b || c)?(Nullable<bool>)b:null;`

Comment: The basis of this question has been asked several times. Here is a great answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215745/conditional-operator-cannot-cast-implicitly

Answer (score 3):

The conditional operator is an expression, thus it needs a return type - also both cases have to have the same return type. In your case, there is no way of determining the return type automatically, thus you need to cast.

Comment: They don't have to be the same type, but the second operand has to be implicitly convertible to the compile-time type of the first.

Comment: @recursive, or the first implicitly convertible to the second. What you want to avoid is having implicit conversions from each operand to the other, as that also causes ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Femaref, equivalent "if" code will be something like

```
private static bool? Assign(bool b, bool c)
    {
        if (b || c)
        {
            return b;
        }
        else return null;
    }
...

a = Assign (b,c)
```

Note the bool? return type. This is what's happening in the conditional operator statement

Comment: It is not *the* ternary operator, it is the conditional operator. A ternary operator is an operator taking three operands, there can be more than one ;)

Comment: In this context the conditional operator is the ternary operator right?

Comment: yes, that is true. however, people seem to use ternary operator and conditional operator interchangeably. While true in C#, it is not necessary true in other languages and looking at all operators, not true at all. Just wanted to point that out.

Comment: Yup, like in Ruby, there is no the ternary operator, but I was consciously using it here taking the context of the discussion. Anyway edited to change to conditional operator.