# Conditional Expression Return Type

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I have two classes implementing the `IMyInterface` and an async method of return type `Task<IMyInterface>`.

Why am I receiving the compiler error "There is no implicit conversion type" for my return statement, `return SomeBooleanDeterminedByTheMethod ? Class1 : new Class2();` and what is the best procedure for resolving this?

Full method:

```
public static async Task<IMyInterface> MyMethodAsync(Subclass1 Class1Child)
{
    var listOfThings = new List<Tuple<int, Class1>>();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var item in SomeCollection)
        {
            var DummyClass1 = new Class1() {IntProperty = 0};
            var computationResult = new Tuple<int, Class1>( DummyClass1.IntProperty, DummyClass1);
            listOfThings.Add(computationResult);
        }
    }

    try 
    {
        var returnedClass1 = (from items in listOfThings
                          orderby items.Item1
                          select items.Item2).FirstOrDefault();
        return returnedClass1.BooleanProperty ? returnedClass1 : new Class2();
    }
    catch ... // Not relevant.
}

class Class1 : IMyInterface
{
    public int IntProperty { get; set;}
    public bool BooleanProperty => IntProperty % 2 == 1; // So, in my example, BooleanProperty will return false.
}

class Class2 : IMyInterface
{
    // This class serves as a separate class to indicate a different Type to be used for my program. 
}

interface IMyInterface { }
```

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: Why post about code not working without providing the relevant code?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli NDA for my code, so I'd have to turn it into a mockup, and the initial thought that the code within the method isn't causing the issue. Give me a sec, will throw up a code example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional operator cannot cast implicitly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215745/conditional-operator-cannot-cast-implicitly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) for the `?:` operator explains:

Given the conditional expression: `condition ? first_expression : second_expression;`

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Since neither Class1 or Class2 are the same type, nor does an implicit conversion exist between the two, you can cast either the `first_expression` or the `second_expression` to the interface type, like so:

```
return SomeBooleanDeterminedByTheMethod ? (IMyInterface)Class1 : new Class2();
```

Then the compiler will know that the expression should evaluate to `IMyInterface`.

Answer (score 3):

You are receiving that error because the compiler can't find a way to convert `Class1` to `Class2`. This is due to the terminary statement `condition ? a : b`. The compiler will try find a matching return type for both `a` and `b`.

In your case cast, you need to cast one of them into `IMyInterface` :

```
return SomeBooleanDeterminedByTheMethod ? new Class1() : (IMyInterface)new Class2();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you need to cast the ternary operator to show the compiler the type that is intended:

```
return SomeBooleanDeterminedByTheMethod
    ? (IMyInterface)new Class1()
    : new Class2();
```