# C# Nullable Type question

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable types and the ternary operator. Why won’t this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work)

for example:

```
int? taxid;
if (ddlProductTax.SelectedValue == "") {
  taxid = null; } 
else {
  taxid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlProductTax.SelectedValue);
} //Correct
```

But

```
int? taxid;
taxid = (ddlProductTax.SelectedValue == "" ? null : Convert.ToInt32(ddlProductTax.SelectedValue)); //Error
```

It error say  and int32 cannot implicit convert.

The (  ? truepart : falsepart); is not short of (if ..else..) ?

Comment: @Gishu, exact duplicate I'd say.  @TatMing check out the answer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: Eric Lippert covered this in a recent blog post: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/05/27/cast-operators-do-not-obey-the-distributive-law.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/05/27/cast-operators-do-not-obey-the-distributive-law.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last two operands of the ternary operator should both yield the same type.

Cast either side to `int?`:

```
taxid = ddlProductTax.SelectedValue == "" ?
                                 (int?)null
                                 : Convert.ToInt32(ddlProductTax.SelectedValue);
```

You can see the exact behavior in the specification:

- [7.12 Conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691313(VS.71).aspx)
- [6.1 Implicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691280(v=VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate
For why it works.
[Nullable types and the ternary operator: why is `? 10 : null` forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work)

Here's the fix:

```
string x = "";
int? taxid;
taxid = (x == "" ? null : (int?) Convert.ToInt32(x)); // add the int? cast
Console.WriteLine(taxid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this correction and it should work.

```
int? taxid; 
taxid = (ddlProductTax.SelectedValue == "" ? null : new int?(Convert.ToInt32(ddlProductTax.SelectedValue))); //Now it works.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little helper method

```
taxid = GetNullableInt32(ddlProductTax.SelectedValue);

public static int? GetNullableInt32(string str)
{
        int result;
        if (Int32.TryParse(str, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's down to the way in which the expressions are evaluated.
With the `? :` construct both of the results must evaulate to the same type and here there is no implicit conversion between the `null` value and an `Int32`.

Try:

```
taxid = (ddlProductTax.SelectedValue == "" )? Convert.ToInt32(null) : Convert.ToInt32(ddlProductTax.SelectedValue);
```