# Passing null values in single line Conditional

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Just a fictional code, but why this won't work? (as the `date` variable is nullable)

```
DateTime? date = textBoxDate.Text != "" ? textBoxDate.Text : null;
```

The error is "There is no explicit conversion between `System.DateTime` and `<null>`

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work

Comment: The left side is checked **after** the right side is checked! So the compiler does not know it should be a `DateTime?` and since they are not the same type, it's trying to mutually convert them. If you convert one of the values to `DateTime?` explicitely, it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DateTime? date = String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxDate.Text) ? 
null as DateTime? : DateTime.Parse(textBoxDate.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming that in reality you've got a conditional which makes rather more sense - `Text` is presumably a string property, and it doesn't make much sense to assign that to a `DateTime?` variable.)

The compiler doesn't know the type of the conditional expression. It doesn't take any account of the fact that there's an assignment to a `DateTime?` variable - it's just trying to find the right type.

Now the type of the expression has to be *either* the type of the LHS, *or* the type of the RHS... but:

- `null` doesn't have a type, so it can't be the type of the RHS
- There's no conversion from `DateTime` to `null` so it can't be the type of the LHS either.

The simplest way to fix this is to give the RHS a real type, so any of:

```
default(DateTime?)
(DateTime?) null
new DateTime?()
```

You could of course make the LHS of type `DateTime?` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`null` can be any reference type, you have to cast it or use the `as` operator:

```
DateTime? date = textBoxDate.Text != "" ? textBoxDate.Text : null as DateTime?;
```

Assuming that textBoxDate can be converted implicitely to Datetime?, which is doubtfull...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what your **textBoxDate.Text** class is like, but I was able to get this to work, compile, and return an expected result.

```
    TextBox textBoxDate = new TextBox();
    textBoxDate.Text = string.Empty;
    DateTime? date = (textBoxDate.Text != "") ? (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(textBoxDate.Text) : null;
```

I think the explicit cast to `(DateTime?)` is what you need

Answer (score 0):

its easy you just quit the initial cast
datetime ? == type not null values permit, 
datetime == with out the ? permit null values

```
DateTime date = textBoxDate.Text != "" ? textBoxDate.Text : null;
```