# If clause with "? :"

Tags: c#, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable types and the ternary operator: why is `? 10 : null` forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden)

I want to assign a value or null value to x (which is a nullable integer) according to a case (you can see below)

```
int? x;
x = stackoverflow.ToString() != "" ? int.Parse(stackoverflow.ToString()) : null;
```

But it gives below error.

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and '<null>'
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the int to a nullable int.

```
x = stackoverflow.ToString() != "" ? 
       (int?)int.Parse(stackoverflow.ToString()) : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
x = stackoverflow.ToString() != "" ? int.Parse(stackoverflow.ToString()) : (int?) null;
```

and see if that works. I didn't test it since I don't know what `stackoverflow` is supposed to be