# Why should convert null value to nullable struct

Tags: c#, type-conversion, nullable

I have a function which gives back a nullable `struct`.
I noticed two similar cases

First: works well:

```
public static GeometricCircle? CircleBySize(GeometricPoint point, double size)
{
    if (size >= epsilon)
        return null;

    return new GeometricCircle(point.Position, new Vector(1, 0, 0), size, true);
}
```

Second: needs to convert the null value to GeometricCircle?

```
public static GeometricCircle? CircleBySize(GeometricPoint point, double size)
{
    return size > epsilon ? new GeometricCircle(point.Position, new Vector(1, 0, 0), size, true) : (GeometricCircle?)null;
}
```

Does anybody know what is the difference?

Comment: If GeometricCircle is a class, then casting is not necessary, in my opinion.

Comment: You are absolutely right. That class is not class but a struct. But the question still remains for me, what is the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden

Comment: I'd say it's because of how the ternary operator is converted into IL. I can't try it now but take a look at how your code is generated with ildasm and it should give your answer.

Comment: @MiklósBalogh `struct` is **NOT** lightweight `class`. `struct` is `Value-Type` (so it's not nullable unless you excplicitly make it with operator `?`) that means that when you assign one `struct` to another variable it's value is copied. While classes are `Reference-Types` (nullables of course) and are on assignment reference of object is assigned.

Comment: @MiklósBalogh I updated your question to make it clear that we're dealing with a `struct`, rather than a `class`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, you are returning `null` when `size >= epsilon`. The compiler knows that `null` is a valid value for a nullable type.

In your second example, you are using the [`?:` ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), which comes with its own set of rules.

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) tells us (my emphasis)...

> Either the type of `first_expression` and `second_expression` must be the same, or an *implicit conversion* must exist from one type to the other.

The key difference here is that `null` cannot be *implicitly* converted into a `GeometricCircle`, (the type of your `first_expression`).

So you have to do it *explicity*, using a cast to `GeometricCircle?`, which is then *implicitly* convertible to `GeometricCircle`.

Comment: What does the ternary operator look like once compiled into IL?

Comment: null can be implicitly converted into a nullable<GeometricCircle> but cannot to GeometricCircle