# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and <null>

Tags: c#, nullable

Why does this not compile?

```
int? number = true ? 5 : null;
```

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and <null>

Comment: Best explanation and example... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden?answertab=active#tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden?answertab=active#tab-top)-top

Answer (score 434, accepted):

The spec (§7.14) says that for conditional expression `b ? x : y`, there are three possibilities, either `x` and `y` both have a type *and* certain *good conditions* are met, only one of `x` and `y` has a type *and* certain *good conditions* are met, or a compile-time error occurs. Here, "certain good conditions" means certain conversions are possible, which we will get into the details of below.

Now, let's turn to the germane part of the spec:

> If only one of `x` and `y` has a type, and both `x` and `y` are implicitly convertible to that type, then that is the type of the conditional expression.

The issue here is that in

```
int? number = true ? 5 : null;
```

only one of the conditional results has a type. Here `x` is an `int` literal, and `y` is `null` which does *not* have a type **and `null` is not implicitly convertible to an `int`**<sup>1</sup>. Therefore, "certain good conditions" aren't met, and a compile-time error occurs.

There *are* two ways around this:

```
int? number = true ? (int?)5 : null;
```

Here we are still in the case where only one of `x` and `y` has a type. Note that `null` *still* does not have a type yet the compiler won't have any problem with this because `(int?)5` and `null` are both implicitly convertible to `int?` (§6.1.4 and §6.1.5).

The other way is obviously:

```
int? number = true ? 5 : (int?)null;
```

but now we have to read a *different* clause in the spec to understand why this is okay:

> If `x` has type `X` and `y` has type `Y` then
>
> - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from `X` to `Y`, but not from `Y` to `X`, then `Y` is the type of the conditional expression.
> - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from `Y` to `X`, but not from `X` to `Y`, then `X` is the type of the conditional expression.
> - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

Here `x` is of type `int` and `y` is of type `int?`. There is no implicit conversion from `int?` to `int`, but there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `int?` so the type of the expression is `int?`.

<sup>1</sup>: Note further that the type of the left-hand side is ignored in determining the type of the conditional expression, a common source of confusion here.

Comment: Good quoting of the spec to illustrate why this happens - +1!

Comment: Another option is `new int?()` in place of `(int?)null`.

Comment: This is also the case if you have a nullable database field type, for example a nullable DateTime and you try and cast data to `DateTime`, when it infact required `(DateTime?)`

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 96):

`null` does not have any identifiable type - it just needs a little prodding to make it happy:

```
int? number = true ? 5 : (int?)null;
```

Comment: Or you can do `int? number = true ? 5 : null as int?;`

Comment: Nice answer nailing the point. Nice related reading: http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/30/what-the-meaning-of-is-is/

Comment: The issue is *not* that `null` doesn't have an identifiable type. The issue is that there is no implicit conversion from `null` to `int`. Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18260915/45914).

Comment: the interesting thing is that `int? number = true ? 5 : (int?)null;` and `int? number = true ? (int?)5 : null;` both compile!! Scratch, scratch

Comment: I cover *exactly* why this happens in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18260915/45914).

Comment: yes, I see it.. thank you both! I accepted your answer, Jason, because it's more throughout

Comment: @David Krmpotic: I feel bad saying this because Marc is a smart guy and I've learned a *lot* from his answers in the past, but this answer is not just less thorough, it misidentifies the issue. `null` not having an identifiable type is okay; `null` not being implicitly convertible to `int` is the issue.

Comment: I see! Thank you both - you for correctly explaining in depth and Marc for giving the hint about what works even though the explanation is "not perfect" ;)

Comment: This is the most concrete and simple answer to the question, Mr Gravell. Bravo!

Answer (score 16):

In `C# 9` this is now allowed [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#target-typed--and-)

> ## Target typed ?? and ?
>
> Sometimes conditional ?? and ?: expressions don’t have an obvious shared type between the branches. Such cases fail today, but C# 9.0 will allow them if there’s a target type that both branches convert to:

```
Person person = student ?? customer; // Shared base type
int? result = b ? 0 : null; // nullable value type
```

Or your example:

```
// Allowed in C# 9.
int? number = true ? 5 : null;
```

Answer (score 7):

The 5 is an `int`, and `null` cannot be implicitly converted to `int`.

Here are ways to work around the issue:

```
int? num = true ? 5 : default(int?);
int? num = true ? 5 : new int?();

int? num = true ? 5 : null as int?;
int? num = true ? 5 : (int?)null;

int? num = true ? (int?)5 : null;
int? num = true ? 5 as int? : null;

int? num = true ? new int?(5) : null;
```

Also, anywhere you see `int?` you could use `Nullable<int>` instead.