# Conditional operator assignment

Tags: c#, casting, conditional-operator

If I can assign any subtype to a supertype reference (upcasting):

```
IWService wService;
wService = new WService();
wService = new WServiceStub();
```

Why can I not assign them in a conditional operator `? :` ?

```
IWService wService = isStub ? new WServiceStub() : new WService();
```

I get this error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between MyNamespace.WServiceStub and MyNamespace.WService

But it's enough to cast one of them to the supertype to compile:

```
IWService wService = isStub ? (IWService)new WServiceStub() : new WService();
```

or

```
IWService wService = isStub ? new WServiceStub() : (IWService)new WService();
```

I don't understand why I need an explicit cast if I'll never get `InvalidCastException`. The conversion is always sure, isn't it?

Is not the following code exactly the same?

```
IWService wService;
if (isStub)
{
    wService = new WServiceStub();
}
else
{
    wService = new WService();
}
```

Comment: If both WService and WServiceStub implement IDisposable as well as IWService, which type should the expression `isStub ? new WServiceStub() : new WService()` have?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the type of the third operand must be convertable to the type of the second, it does not look at the left-hand side of the assignment when determining the result type of the expression.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. The second can also be convertible to the type of the third. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18260915/860585