# Parsing a string to an int difference

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to understand whats happening and why it doesnt work. I was trying to convert `"34"` to the int `34`. I wish to know why there is a difference (and why my version didnt work):

My version:

```c
var cell = GetSpecificString();
return (cell == "") ? null : int.Parse(cell);
```

SO version:

```cs
var cell = GetSpecificString();
if (int.TryParse(cell, out int i)) return i;
return null;
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, as I want to know whats happening here.

Does not work implies here that the Intellisense is complaining because there is no conversion between '' and 'int'. But I want to return a nullable int, so this seems weird to me.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Do you get an exception? What is your input-data?

Comment: We need more context. An `int` cannot be `null`.

Comment: input data is irrelevant, i want a nullable int from a string that, if malformed should return null.

Answer (score 2):

The first version doesn't work because the conditional operator doesn't allow it whereas the second approach uses an `if`. The rules for the conditional operator are stricter. Both types must be compatible but `null` and `int` are not. You could achieve it by using:

```
return (cell == "") ? (int?)null : int.Parse(cell);
```

However, i'd really use `int.TryParse` since an empty string is not the only invalid value:

```
return int.TryParse(cell, out int parsedValue) ? parsedValue : new int?();
```

Comment: I'd also recommend to use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace( cell )`.

Comment: @Fildor: I'd recommend using `TryParse`, that handles every invalid input

Comment: I wrote the comment before your edit. I agree with your solution. But it still stands in cases where OP would write `cell == ""` to use the utility function instead.

Answer (score 1):

**There is already good explanation on stack overflow for this problem:** 
For complete explanation refer [Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and <null>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260528/type-of-conditional-expression-cannot-be-determined-because-there-is-no-implicit)

The spec (§7.14) says that for conditional expression b ? x : y, there are three possibilities, either x and y both have a type and certain good conditions are met, only one of x and y has a type and certain good conditions are met, or a compile-time error occurs.

**If only one of x and y has a type, and both x and y are implicitly convertible to that type, then that is the type of the conditional expression.**