# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between two objects with same base type

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, conditional-operator

I have read this stackoverflow topic:

[Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and <null>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260528/type-of-conditional-expression-cannot-be-determined-because-there-is-no-implicit)

I understand there is a risk of the compiler not understanding one of the types in ternary operator. However, my both classes inherit the same base class.

This is what I currently have:

```
public async Task Handle(IClientPendingIntegrationEvent message) {
    Command<Unit> command = _requestContext.SourceType == RequestSourceType.Backoffice
            ? new CreateManualUserEventCommand(message.UserId, eventType, UserEventDomain.Registration, message.Reason)
            : new CreateUserEventCommand(message.UserId, eventType, UserEventOriginType.System, UserEventDomain.Registration, message.Reason);

    await _mediator.Send(command);
}


public class CreateManualUserEventCommand : Command<Unit>
{
    public CreateManualUserEventCommand(
        string userId,
        UserEventType userEventType,
        UserEventDomain domain,
        string comment = null)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        Type = userEventType;
        Domain = domain;
        Comment = comment;
    }

    public string UserId { get; private set; }

    public UserEventType Type { get; private set; }

    public UserEventDomain Domain { get; private set; }

    public string Comment { get; private set; }
}


public class CreateUserEventCommand : Command<Unit>
    {
        public CreateUserEventCommand(
            string userId,
            UserEventType type,
            UserEventOriginType createdByOrigin,
            UserEventDomain domain,
            string comment = null)
        {
            UserId = userId;
            Type = type;
            CreatedByOrigin = createdByOrigin;
            Domain = domain;
            Comment = comment;
        }

        public string UserId { get; }

        public UserEventType Type { get; }

        public UserEventOriginType CreatedByOrigin { get; }

        public UserEventDomain Domain { get; }

        public string Comment { get; }
    }
```

This is the exact error the compiler throws.

> ### Error CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between
>
> 'MFG.Auditing.Application.Features.Backoffice.UserEvents.Commands.CreateManualUserEvent.CreateManualUserEventCommand'
> and
> 'MFG.Auditing.Application.Features.System.UserEvents.Commands.CreateUserEvent.CreateUserEventCommand'

I understand that I can easily rework this with if and else but I need to use ternary operator here.

Comment: "However, my both classes inherit the same base class." But neither expression *is* that base class type. The compiler doesn't try to find some best common base type. Please read the accepted answer on the other question carefully - it does go through the spec.

Comment: Basically if you case *either* of the operands to the base class type, it'll be fine.

Comment: You can fix it by casting - put `(Command<Unit>)` in front of either of the `new`s in the ternary statement.

Comment: Note that this was was fixed in C# 9 with target-typed conditionals: [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxANwKYCcoDMCeAfAAQCYBGAWAChgB7agGwAJgGBeBhdAV1QG5KAhCAGdUDdKiGc6CVkwYB+BjFQB3BgEEAFAEoGIJaob8dfCpQIBmBsSPDRAbwYBfc1Zvq9tkQ0cuKl6yIjT0FvXyA===)

Comment: Thank you all. Simply casting either  to (Command<Unit>)  works. As Jon Skeet mentioned  the compiler doesn't try to find some best common base type.