# Attempting to assign null to nullable int results in "There is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'null'" error

Tags: c#, .net, int, nullable

```
public List<Tuple<int, int, int, string, int, int, Tuple<bool, bool, int?>>> 
    GetValues(int someId, int someOtherlId)
{
    var t = new List<Tuple<int, int, int, string, int, int, Tuple<bool, bool, int?>>>();
    using (var context = new Entities(ConnString))
    {
        var pc = context.SomeTable.Where(c => c.SomeId == someId && 
            c.SomeOtherId == someOtherId).OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList();
        t.AddRange(pc.Select(cols => new Tuple<int, int, int, string, int, int, Tuple<bool, bool, int?>>
            (cols.Id, cols.someId, cols.someOtherId, cols.ColumnName, cols.MinDataLength,
            cols.MaxDataLength, new Tuple<bool, bool, int?>(cols.Required, cols.Eav.HasValue && cols.Eav.Value,
                cols.AttribId.HasValue ? cols.AttribId.Value : null))));
    }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Can't figure out why this code won't compile and generates "There is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'null'" error.

In that second Tuple the int? is consistently marked as nullable so why is it being detected as a normal int by the compiler in `t.AddRange` which generates "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and ''" error at `cols.AttribId.HasValue ? cols.AttribId.Value : null`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden?rq=1

Comment: That `Tuple` is just hideous! At least extend that class into a custom class!

Comment: @m-y Perhaps, but it surely beats DTO as a method of transferring data from DAL to BI layer... at least in my book.

Comment: Just extend the Tuple to a simpler name, Tuple isn't sealed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to add an `int?` to a tuple that already accepts `int?` why not just add it directly to your tuple—i.e. replace:

```
new Tuple<bool, bool, int?>(..., cols.AttribId.HasValue ? cols.AttribId.Value : null)
```

With

```
new Tuple<bool, bool, int?>(..., cols.AttribId)
```

Or to a little bit cleaner, take advantage of type inference with [`Tuple.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create.aspx):

```
Tuple.Create(..., cols.AttribId)
```

Comment: Yes, that's even better obviously, I converted from non-nullable to nullable so that check is no longer needed anyway as you pointed out...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
cols.AttribId.HasValue ? (int?)cols.AttribId.Value : null
```

What's happening is that the C# ternary there has to exist implicit conversion between both values. When you write:

```
cols.AttribId.HasValue ? cols.AttribId.Value : null
```

`cols.AttribId.Value` is an `int` which cannot be converted to `null`. An `int?` however *can* be converted to `null`.

Comment: That worked, care to explain why? I mean, AttribId is nullable field in the DB... I'm assuming that AttribId.Value cannot be null and is therefore an int...

Comment: Edited answer withe explanation

Comment: Note that it will also work the other way around: `cols.AttribId.HasValue ? cols.AttribId.Value : (int?)null`.