# How to work with null, dbnull and datetime in short if condition

Tags: c#, ado.net

I retrieve some datetime data from SQL-Server. In my Web.Api Controller, I advise the database data to my object.

This works:

```
 if (reader["images_lastupload"] == DBNull.Value)
 {
      mydata.ImagesLastUpload = null;
 }
 else
 {
      mydata.ImagesLastUpload = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["images_lastupload"].ToString());
 }
```

The db field "Images_lastupload" can be NULL. So I want to check this.

mydata.ImagesLastUpload is a nullable datetime. Everything works fine.

But the short Version does not work:

```
 mydata.ImagesLastUpload = (reader["images_lastupload"] == DBNull.Value) ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["images_lastupload"].ToString());
```

How can I make the short Version work? My German error is:

*Der Typ des bedingten Ausdrucks kann nicht bestimmt werden, weil keine implizite Konvertierung zwischen '' und 'System.DateTime' erfolgt.*

Comment: What is wrong with your `if` block, it looks more readable than conditional operator ?

Comment: It is more readable. But my code is so long, I must stuff it where it´s possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion between `null` and `DateTime`. You can cast `null` to nullable `DateTime`:

```
mydata.ImagesLastUpload = (reader["images_lastupload"] == DBNull.Value) ? 
    (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["images_lastupload"].ToString());
```

Or use any other approach suggested at [Nullable types and the ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden?lq=1)

Comment: OK, I see, that your changes are "(DateTime?)null". Can you explain short, what this meens? "DateTime?" meens it is nullable? What does the brackets meen? Thx. *EDIT* I did not saw your link at the bottom. THX !

Comment: @Leparevilo `DateTime?` is a short syntax for `Nullable<DateTime>`. Brackets is a casting (i.e. explicit conversion)