# How to initialize an empty value to a datetime variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check if the `DateTime` variables `"starttime"` and `"endtime"` have `null` values and then trying to initialize to an `empty` value as below, but I'm running into below compilation errors. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
string htmllink = "";
DateTime? starttime = null;
DateTime? endtime = null;
htmllink = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "html_link")) ? "" : rdr.GetString(3);
starttime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "start_time")) ? "" : rdr.GetString(4);
endtime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "end_time")) ? "" : rdr.GetString(5);

results.htmllist.Add(new gethtmllist() { resulthtmllink = htmllink, 
    duration = (starttime - endtime).ToString() });
```

**Error:**

> Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'

UPDATE:-

```
                string htmllink = "";
                htmllink = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "html_link")) ? "" : rdr.GetString(3);                    
                DateTime? starttime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "start_time")) ? new DateTime() : rdr.GetDateTime(4);
                DateTime?  endtime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "end_time")) ? new DateTime() : rdr.GetDateTime(5);

               results.htmllist.Add(new gethtmllist()
                {
                    resulthtmllink = htmllink,
                    duration = starttime.HasValue && endtime.HasValue ? (endtime.Value - starttime.Value).ToString() : ""
                });
```

Comment: Does rdr have a GetDateTime method? Or GetValue returning object that you might be able to cast? If all else fails, pass the string to DateTime.Parse(). Anyway, a null is just a null. Null is easy. Where did you get the idea that null means anything but empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try an string.Empty to test:`starttime = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Now;`

It is successed. So your code could be:

```
starttime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "start_time")) ? (DateTime?)null : rdr.GetDateTime(4);
    endtime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "end_time")) ? (DateTime?)null: rdr.GetDateTime(5);
```

Update 1:
.Net Fiddle example for string.Empty: [Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ruc5qZ)

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you are trying to set `starttime` and `endtime` to string values, when you have initially declared them as `DateTime?` types. To solve this, you need to either declare them as strings to begin with, or convert the values to a valid `DateTime?` type during the assignment.

```
DateTime? starttime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "start_time")) 
    ? null 
    : rdr.GetDateTime(4);

DateTime? endtime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "end_time")) 
    ? null 
    : rdr.GetDateTime(5);
```

Then, when you're calculating your duration, you may have to check for null (or `HasValue` in the case of a `DateTime?`). I also changed the order of your operands, so that `starttime` is being subtracted from `endtime` (otherwise you will likely have a negative `duration`):

```
string duration = (starttime.HasValue && endtime.HasValue) 
    ? (endtime - starttime).ToString() 
    : "0";
```

Comment: this gives an error `Error 2 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime'
`

Answer (score 1):

You can't set dates to a string

```
starttime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "start_time")) ? "" : rdr.GetString(4);
endtime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "end_time")) ? "" : rdr.GetString(5);
```

should be

```
starttime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "start_time")) ? new DateTime() : rdr.GetDateTime(4);
endtime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "end_time")) ? new DateTime() : rdr.GetDateTime(5);
```

Comment: am getting duration as 00:00:00,I want to send an empty string..how to do it,updated the latest code for info?

Comment: an empty string cannot be a datetime.  You could set it to null if that's what you're looking to do, couldn't really tell your intentions from your original post.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [`DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method in order to convert strings to valid `DateTime` object.

When using [Nullable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) like `DateTime?` you should check if there is value present by using `HasValue` property, the  to get the value please use `Value` property.

```
string htmllink = "";
htmllink = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "html_link")) ? "" : rdr.GetString(3);
DateTime? starttime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "start_time")) ? default(DateTime?) : DateTime.Parse(rdr.GetString(4));
DateTime? endtime = (dbNullCheck.isColumnNull(rdr, "end_time")) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(rdr.GetString(5));

results.htmllist.Add(new gethtmllist() { resulthtmllink = htmllink, 
duration = starttime.HasValue && endtime.HasValue ? (starttime.Value - endtime.Value).ToString() : "there is no duration" });
```

In order to use `null` in trenary expression with nullable types remember to cast it to the expected type by using `(DateTime?)null` or `default(DateTime?)`. Please see [why this is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden).

Comment: Is should not even compile. Parse expects a string, not a bool.

Comment: Addressed this issue in current edit. Typing code on mobile is not what you should really do 

Comment: this throws an error `Error 2 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime' `

Comment: Forgot about that C# quirk. Please cast that nulls to expected `DateTime?` type or use `default(DateTime?)` in order to fix that error. Please see [why it is happening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-is-10-null-forbidden). I will update the example code.