# What is causing this 'No Implicit Conversion' error?

Tags: c#

I have a class and 2 subclasses:

```
public class User
{
    public string eRaiderUsername { get; set; }
    public int AllowedSpaces { get; set; }
    public ContactInformation ContactInformation { get; set; }
    public Ethnicity Ethnicity { get; set; }
    public Classification Classification { get; set; }
    public Living Living { get; set; }
}

public class Student : User
{
    public Student()
    {
        AllowedSpaces = AppSettings.AllowedStudentSpaces;
    }
}

public class OrganizationRepresentative : User
{
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public OrganizationRepresentative()
    {
        AllowedSpaces = AppSettings.AllowedOrganizationSpaces;
    }
}
```

I have created a data model to capture form data and to return the correct object type for the user:

```
public class UserData
{
    public string eRaiderUsername { get; set; }
    public int Ethnicity { get; set; }
    public int Classification { get; set; }
    public int Living { get; set; }
    public string ContactFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ContactLastname { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string ContactCellPhone { get; set; }
    public bool IsRepresentingOrganization { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    public User GetUser()
    {
        var user = (IsRepresentingOrganization) ? new OrganizationRepresentative() : new Student();
    }
}
```

However, my ternary operation in the `GetUser()` method is failing with this error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between {namespace}.OrganizationRepresentative and {namespace}.Student.

What am I missing?

Comment: Both classes know nothing about each other but only commonality is the User base class. you should be doing a cast to User for which ever object you are trying to instantiated because you cannot create and assign an object different to a potentially other concrete object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828950/why-doesnt-this-c-sharp-code-compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to explicitly cast the first branch of the ternary expression to the base type (`User`) so that the compiler can determine what type the expression can evaluate to.

```
var user = (IsRepresentingOrganization) 
               ? (User)new OrganizationRepresentative()
               : new Student();
```

The compiler won't automatically deduce which base type should be used for the expression, so you have to specify it manually.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why didn't you need to cast `new Student()` to `User` as well?

Comment: @Alex, only one of the operand of conditional operator could be cast to base class,

Comment: @Alex once you've specified the type of the first branch (`User`), the compiler can find an implicit conversion from the type of the second branch (`Student`) because it's a simple widening cast.

Comment: To follow on from what Adam said, a ternary if can only return one type (or the types must be implicitly castable). That is to say, you can't do something like (a == true ? "X" : 5) - you would need to change it to (a == true ? "X" : "5"). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ty67wk28.aspx