# c# assign value for nullable boolean

Tags: c#, nullable

I am trying to play around with the [?: Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) on assigning a value into a nullable boolean variable.

This the original code which works fine

```
bool? result;
var condition = 3;

if (condition == 1)
    result = true;
else if (condition == 2)
     result = false;
else result = null;
```

After I change the code, it hit an error, and I fix it after searching the internet

```
// before (error occur)
result = condition == 1 ? true : (condition == 2 ? false : null);

// after (fixed error)
result = condition == 1 ? true : (condition == 2 ? false : (bool?)null); 
// *or
result = condition == 1 ? true : (condition == 2 ? (bool?)false : null);
```

I understand that both expressions have to be of the same type, but **why it only required to convert one expression but not all of the expression?** which make me confused.

from my understanding `bool and bool?` or `bool? and null` should be still considered the not same type, but it works in the situation.

Any advice to this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out for good explanation. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828950/why-doesnt-this-c-sharp-code-compile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this C# code compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828950/why-doesnt-this-c-sharp-code-compile)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a ternary conditional operator, the compiler requires that each of the possible assigned values are of the same type.

In the segment `(condition == 2 ? false : null)`, the two possible values are `false` and `null`. The compiler sees `false` as a `bool`, so it will error as `null` isn't a valid alternate value for a `bool`.

By prefixing either with `(bool?)`, you make it clear that you're actually assigning a nullable boolean, making the compiler happy because it knows both values are indeed the same type.