# Why doesn't the conditional operator correctly allow the use of "null" for assignment to nullable types?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Nullable types and the ternary operator. Why won’t this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work)
>   [Conditional operator assignment with nullable<value> types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/conditional-operator-assignment-with-nullablevalue-types)

This will not compile, stating "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and ''"

```
task.ActualEndDate = TextBoxActualEndDate.Text != "" ? DateTime.Parse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text) : null;
```

This works just fine

```
 if (TextBoxActualEndDate.Text != "")
    task.ActualEndDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text);
else
    task.ActualEndDate = null;
```

Comment: Can you get rid of the dependencies on your code, so we can reproduce this? Replace `task.ActualEndDate` with a local variable, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't work because the compiler will not insert an implicit conversion on both sides at once, and `null` requires an implicit conversion to become a nullable type.

Instead, you can write

```
task.ActualEndDate = TextBoxActualEndDate.Text != "" ? 
    DateTime.Parse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text) : new DateTime?();
```

This only requires one implicit conversion (`DateTime` to `DateTime?`).

Alternatively, you can cast either left side:

```
task.ActualEndDate = TextBoxActualEndDate.Text != "" ? 
    (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text) : null;
```

This also requires only one implicit conversion.

Comment: You really should use a DateTime.TryParse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text, out someDateVar) there. Never trust input to give you a parseable string.

Comment: Validation occurs in a couple places prior to this parse, and I would prefer an exception now rather than one when I attempt to insert DateTime.Min into the database.

Answer (score 4):

The conditional operator doesn't look at what the value is being returned into.  It only looks at the values it's being asked to choose between: a DateTime and null.  It can't identify these as instances of the same type (because null isn't a valid DateTime), hence the error.  You and I know that `Nullable<DateTime>` could do the job, but the conditional operator isn't allowed to introduce "larger" types: it's only allowed to look at the types of the two expressions it's choosing between.  (Thanks to [Aaronaught](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38360/aaronaught) in comments for clarification of this point and a nice clarifying example.)

To work around this, give the operator a hint by casting the DateTime:

```
TextBoxActualEndDate.Text != "" ? (DateTime?)(DateTime.Parse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text)) : null;
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Mostly correct (+1): `DateTime.Parse` returns a `DateTime` (not a `Nullable<DateTime>`), which is a value type and has no conversion to or from `null`. The compiler doesn't have the ability to introduce "larger" types into the equation when it tries to resolve the expression, it can only work with the types that are actually there.  It's the same reason you can't write `Stream s = expr ? new MemoryStream() : new FileStream(...)`.

Comment: Aaronaught: great explanation - I will fold that in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of

[Nullable types and the ternary operator: why is `? 10 : null` forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work/858557#858557)

My answer to

[Conditional operator cannot cast implicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215745/conditional-operator-cannot-cast-implicitly/2215959#2215959)

gives an analysis that is germane to this question.

I'll also be blogging about a similar issue with the conditional operator in April; watch the blog for details.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx was very informative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that null is of type `object` so you have to cast it to the correct type, like this:

```
task.ActualEndDate = TextBoxActualEndDate.Text != "" ? 
    DateTime.Parse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text) : ((DateTime?) null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most correct way (IMO) is to do this

```
task.ActualEndDate = TextBoxActualEndDate.Text != "" ? 
    (DateTime?)(DateTime.Parse(TextBoxActualEndDate.Text) : null);
```

I use the null collaescing operator frequently in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error probably which you get in this situation:

> error CS0173: Type of conditional
>   expression cannot be determined
>   because there is no implicit
>   conversion between '' and 'int')

The compiler is  is explaining that it does not know how convert `null` into a `DateTime`.

---

**Fix:**

you need to `cast` `explicitly` the `expression` which may return `null` to the `nullable` type.  This will work

```
((DateTime?) null);
```