# Why can't I set a nullable int to null in a ternary if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The C# code below:

```
int? i;
i = (true ? null : 0);
```

gives me the error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot
>   be determined because there is no
>   implicit conversion between '<null>'
>   and 'int'

Shouldn't this be valid?  What am i missing here?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450866 which was in turn a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215745/conditional-operator-cannot-cast-implicitly/2215959#2215959 for an analysis of the issue.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The compiler tries to evaluate the right-hand expression. `null` is `null` and the `0` is an `int` literal, not `int?`. The compiler is trying to tell you that it can't determine what type the expression should evaluate as. There's no implicit conversion between `null` and `int`, hence the error message.

You need to tell the compiler that the expression should evaluate as an `int?`. There is an implicit conversion between `int?` and `int`, or between `null` and `int?`, so either of these should work:

```
int? x = true ? (int?)null : 0;

int? y = true ? null : (int?)0;
```

Answer (score 21):

You need to use the **default()** keyword rather than null when dealing with ternary operators.

Example:

```
int? i = (true ? default(int?) : 0);
```

Alternately, you could just cast the null:

```
int? i = (true ? (int?)null : 0);
```

Personally I stick with the `default()` notation, it's just a preference, really. But you should ultimately stick to just one specific notation, IMHO.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

The portion `(true ? null : 0)` becomes a function in a way. This function needs a return type. When the compiler needs to figure out the return type it can't.

This works:

```
int? i;
i = (true ? null : (int?)0);
```