# How does cast in C#/.NET 3.5 work for types with '?'

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable types and the ternary operator. Why won’t this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work)

This is my code which works

```
public decimal? Get()
{
    var res = ...
    return res.Count() > 0 ? res.First() : (decimal?) null;
}
```

and this one doesn't work

```
public decimal? Get()
{
    var res = ...
    return res.Count() > 0 ? res.First() : null;
}
```

giving the compiler error:

> Error 1 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'decimal' and '`<null>`'

I wonder why? any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450866/why-doesnt-the-conditional-operator-correctly-allow-the-use-of-null-for-assign

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/conditional-operator-assignment-with-nullablevalue-types

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215745/conditional-operator-cannot-cast-implicitly

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766932/why-cant-i-set-a-nullable-int-to-null-in-a-ternary-if-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. Both the "?" en ":" parts of that conditional operator need to have the same type or must at least be implicitly converted to the same Type. And a lone `null` doesn't have a good Type.

*Maybe* you could use .FirstOrDefault(). Depending on the type of your `res` that would give a `null` or `0m`.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is covered in section 7.13 of the C# language spec.

In short the types of the two expressions in the ternary operator must be * compatible* in order for the compiler to determine the type of the ternary expression.  In this case the two types being considered are

1. `decimal`
2. `null`

The `decimal` type is a value type and hence null is not convertible to it.  The value `null` has no associated type.  This prevents the compiler from determining the type of the expression and leads to a compilation error.

In the first example the second type is `decimal?`.  There is a conversion between `decimal` and `decimal?` so the compiler picks `decimal?` as the type.

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic, but...

Using [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx) is a bit pointless when all you need to know is whether or not the sequence has any elements. `Count` will loop through all the elements whereas [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) will stop as soon as it hits the first element:

```
public decimal? Get()
{
    var res = ...
    return res.Any() ? res.First() : (decimal?)null;
}
```

Or maybe this:

```
public decimal? Get()
{
    var res = ...
    using (var e = res.GetEnumerator())
    {
        return e.MoveNext() ? e.Current : (decimal?)null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing res is an array of decimals i.e. decimal[]. This would be because you have declared res like this:

```
var res = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
```

and not like this:

```
var res = { 1.0, 2.0, null };
```

so there is no reason for the compiler to think res is an array of nullable decimals.

Now you are using a ternary operator which must always return the same (or an equivalent castable) type from both sides.

But as res.First() is a 'decimal' and your null by default is untyped it just makes your null equivalent to the type of your first argument (res.First() i.e. a decimal). By forcing the null to be typed as a nullable decimal ('decimal?') you are actually forcing the compiler to treat  res.First() as a nullable decimal too.

However, a better solution overall for you is this:

```
public decimal? Get()
{
    decimal?[] res = ...
    return res.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: The "better solution overalll" assumes `res` contains nullable decimals, which you've already assumed *is not* the case at the beginning of your answer. Given a world where `res` may not contain nullable decimals, then the "better overall solution" is incorrect.

Comment: Great point - I thought FirstOrDefault would return a NULL but default(decimal) is in fact 0.0M.

Answer (score 0):

In second case you can use `res.FirstOrDefault()`.

`IEnumerable<T>.FirstOrDefault()` returns first `T` in set or `default<T>` if set is empty: `null` for classes and some default value for structs, in common case - `0`.

```
public decimal? Get()
{
    var res = ...
    return res.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

which is equal to

```
public decimal? Get()
{
    var res = ...
    return res.Count() > 0 ? res.First() : default(decimal?);
}
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` for a `decimal` list would be 0M, regardless of whether you cast the value to `decimal?` afterwards. This presents a problem. Is 0M a case of a value not existing or is 0M the first value in the list?