# Whats wrong with setting nullable double to null?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why can't I set a nullable int to null in a ternary if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766932/why-cant-i-set-a-nullable-int-to-null-in-a-ternary-if-statement)
>   [Nullable types and the ternary operator. Why won't this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858080/nullable-types-and-the-ternary-operator-why-wont-this-work)

Whats wrong with the below

```
public double? Progress { get; set; }
Progress = null; // works
Progress = 1; // works
Progress = (1 == 2) ? 0.0 : null; // fails
```

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'double' and '<null>'

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766932/why-cant-i-set-a-nullable-int-to-null-in-a-ternary-if-statement

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When using the `?:` operator, it has to resolve to a single type, or types that has an implicit conversion between them. In your case, it will either return a `double` or `null`, and double does not have an implicit conversion to `null`.

You will see that

```
Progress = (1 == 2) ? (double?)0.0 : null;
```

works fine, since there *is* an implicit conversion between `nullable double` and `null`

Answer (score 0):

The double is `0.0` in this case

```
Progress = (1 == 2) ? (double?)0.0 : null; // works
```