# Have two variable types

Tags: c#

I am attempting to make a suvat calculator and require to have some form of way to have two different types of variable stored in one variable.

For those unaware of suvat. suvat equations are a collection of equations which allows for each of the five variables to be found from only three known variables.

This means that I need to be able to have a variable hold a float and a null value. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: nullable types ftw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign Null value to Non-Nullable type variable in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491889/how-to-assign-null-value-to-non-nullable-type-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a variable to hold both a float or null, you need to use nullable types.  For example, you can use "float?" as the type:

```
float? myFloat = null;
```

If you need to hold a double or null, use the nullable double type:

```
double? myDouble = null;
```

etc.

Comment: Also known as "[Nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)".

Comment: Unfortunately, this is pretty much what I need; however, I cannot seem to convert this type to a double. Each conversion I try doesn't allow me to use Math.sqrt(variable)

Comment: @TheAndOnlyFin, after testing to be sure myFloat doesn't equal null, try: Math.Sqrt((double)myFloat);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a class that contains the types you need. For example, if you need a float and a string (you said `null`, but that is not a type, so I'm using `string`, which can be null):

```
class SomeClassName
{
    public float FloatValue {get; set;}
    public string StringValue {get; set;}
}
```

Now you can create a variable of type `SomeClassName` and assign it both a float and a string:

```
SomeClassName suvat = new SomeClassName();
suvat.FloatValue = 1.2;
suvat.StringValue = null;
```