# Conditional expression cannot be determined error with ternary operator

Tags: c#, .net

The following error comes with `ternary operator`.

> Error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '' and 'int'

Why is this error appearing even though I have specified `(int)(result)` for the `ExecuteScalar` result? How can we correct it?

**CODE**

```
    public int? GetWINFromAssociateID(int associateID)
    {
        int? WIN =null;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string commandText = DataLayerConstants.GetWINFromAssociateIDCommand;
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payroll_svc_assoc_id", associateID);

                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
                WIN = result == DBNull.Value ? null : (int)(result);
            }
        }
        return WIN;
    }
```

**UPDATED REFERENCES**

1. [Conditional operator cannot cast implicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215745/conditional-operator-cannot-cast-implicitly/2215959#2215959)
2. [Type inference woes, part one - by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx)

Comment: Read this answer and the links you'll find there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2452375/385844

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cast your null in ternary operator to int?:

```
Win=result==DBNull.Value?(int?)null:(int?)result;
```

Comment: It's not necessary to cast both null and result; casting either one is sufficient.

Comment: In this case it is necessary due to result has type object.

Comment: Ok, I was reading too hastily; my comment was only half correct.  I should have written "It's not necessary to cast both `null` and `result`; casting `result` is sufficient" (because there is an implicit conversion from null to `int?`).

Answer (score 0):

It is because there `Command.ExecuteScalar` returns an instance of `object` type; and you may not be returning an integer.

You need to use `int.Parse` or better int.TryParse;

```
int.Parse(result.ToString());
```

OR

```
int temp = -1;
int.TryParse(result.ToString(), out temp);
```