# Why this Conditional operator error?

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional operator assignment with Nullable<value> types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/conditional-operator-assignment-with-nullablevalue-types)

Hi,
Why this doesn't work?

```
  DateTime? SomeNullableDateTime = string.IsNullOrEmpty("") ? null : Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/1982");
```

Is it an error somewhere? The problem seems to be the null because

```
  DateTime? SomeNullableDateTime = string.IsNullOrEmpty("") ? Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/1982") : Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/1982");
```

Works fine..

Thanks

Comment: -sigh- What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: There are quite a few duplicates of this - look in the Related bar on the RHS.

Comment: ok i'm sorry I vote to delete..

Comment: Even "doesn't want to compile" isn't an appropriate error description. You already got quite some rep, you should really know this by now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both conditional values need to be of the same type or allow implicit conversion from one type to another, like so:

```
DateTime? SomeNullableDateTime = string.IsNullOrEmpty("") ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/1982");
```

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), but to summarize:

> Either the type of first_expression
>   and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must
>   exist from one type to the other.

Comment: Can you cast a DateTime to DateTime? directly like that?  That's neat if you can..

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone: Yup, you can.

Comment: @Kieren - Yes you can, but it's actually not needed in this case as there is an implicit conversion.

Comment: "need to be of the same type" - actually the rules are a little more involved.

Comment: @Henk - Correct, updated to indicate implicit conversions are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Because `null` and `Convert.ToDateTime` are not the same type.

You can use this:

```
DateTime? SomeNullableDateTime = string.IsNullOrEmpty("") ? (DateTime?)null : new DateTime?(Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/1982"));
```