# C# inline conditional nullabel value types

Tags: c#, nullable, value-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional operator assignment with Nullable<value> types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/conditional-operator-assignment-with-nullablevalue-types)

in the following code snippet *company.ParentID* is a **int?** and *parrent* a reference type.
this code is a syntax error.
is there anyway to fix this inline conditional??

`company.ParentID = (parent == null ? null: (parent.ID));`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cast parent.Id to an int?

`company.ParentID = (parent == null) ? null : (int?)parent.ID;`