# C#.net can't assign null to a variable in an inline if statement

Tags: c#, .net

I was just wondering why the following code doesn't work (please keep in mind that I set `age` to be nullable):

```
myEmployee.age = conditionMet ? someNumber : null;
```

Yet the following works fine:

```
if(conditionMet)
{
    myEmployee.age = someNumber;
}
else
{
    myEmployee.age = null;
}
```

Why can't I set the value to null in a conditional operator?? All these `if` statements in my code is not nice.

Thanks.

Comment: Please define _code doesn't work_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional operator assignment with Nullable<value> types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/conditional-operator-assignment-with-nullablevalue-types)

Comment: please note - it's not an 'inline if'; it's the *conditional operator*.  `if` statements are statements (i.e. without value); the conditional operator `?:` is an expression (and hence why you've had this issue as the types must be the same or implicitly convertible).

Comment: My apologies, guess I used the wrong keywords when searching and hadn't realized that this has already been asked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The types on both sides have to be the same (or be implicitly convertible):

```
myEmployee.age = conditionMet ? someNumber : (int?)null;
```

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Comment: +1, in this case the ternary operator's rules for *true-expr* and *false-expr* play a role in it as well.

Comment: Any reason you went after the `null` instead of casting as `(int?)someNumber`? Do you find that more readable?  I only ask because both you and RedFilter chose the same side.

Comment: Both are possible - personally I find it easier to read this way, but it's just personal preference.

Comment: @Marc: I would choose that because `int` is logically convertible to a nullable integer but `null` is not logically convertible to an integer.

Answer (score 8):

You can, just be clear about the type that `null` should be interpreted as:

```
myEmployee.age = conditionMet ? someNumber : (int?)null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at what the documentation has to say:

> [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) The default value for a nullable type variable sets HasValue to false. The Value is undefined.

The default is thus `null`. Which means that you can simply do:

```
if (conditionMet)
    myEmployee.age = someNumber;
```

There is no need for more obscure code syntax.

---

If required you can initialize it with `null` in advance, if it somehow was not the default, like so:

```
myEmployee.age = null;

if (conditionMet)
    myEmployee.age = someNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

The types of the parts of the ternary statement must be implicitly castable to a common base.  In the case of `int` and `null`, they aren't.  You can solve this by making `age` a `Nullable<int>` (or `int?`) and casting `someNumber` to `int?`.

EDIT to clarify: you can set the value to `null` with a ternary statement with proper casting.  The problem here isn't that you're trying to set a value to `null` with a ternary statement.  It's that the compiler-inferred return types of the two expressions involved in the ternary statement cannot be implicitly casted to a common base type.

Comment: You missed the last line in the question I think.