# There is no implicit conversion between null and datetime

Tags: c#

Following code read a piece data from given `DataRow`(modelValue) and parse it to a `nullable` `DateTime` instance.

**Question**: Please see the code sections under `L1 & L2` where both are technically equal (If i am not making any schoolboy error). However, `L1` works as expected but not `L2`. I am getting

> there is no implicit conversion between null and datetime

when I execute the code under `L2`. Can someone advise me ?

```
        DateTime? CallBack;

        var callBackDate = modelValue["CallBack"] == DBNull.Value ? null : modelValue["CallBack"].ToString();
        //Parsing
        DateTime cdate;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(callBackDate, out cdate))
            cdate = DateTime.MinValue;


        //L1
        if (cdate==DateTime.MinValue)
            CallBack = null;
        else
           CallBack = cdate.Date;

       //L2  
       CallBack = cdate == DateTime.MinValue?null:cdate.Date;
```

Comment: This has been asked before a lot, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/conditional-operator-assignment-with-nullablevalue-types). IMO, the cleanest workaround that still uses `?:` is `... ? default(DateTime?) : ...`.

Comment: The compiler fails to infer that the expression `cdate == DateTime.MinValue?null:cdate.Date` should return `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` (because `cdate.Date` is `DateTime`). So, it tries to convert null to `DateTime`... and fails.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
(Z) ? X : Y
```

The ternary operator requires that an implicit conversion exists from the second operand (X) to the third operand (Y), or from Y to X.

Since `null` cannot be implicitly converted to `DateTime`, nor `DateTime` to `null`, the expression cannot be evaluated. More on this: [Type inference woes by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx).

You have to cast `null` to `DateTime?`. By doing so, X will be of type `DateTime?` and Y will be of type `DateTime`. Since there is an implicit conversion from `DateTime` to `DateTime?`, the expression can be evaluated, and it will return a value of type `DateTime?`.

Alternatively, and following the same logic, you could also cast the third operand Y to `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 41):

You need to tell the compiler that the null should be treated as `DateTime?`. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know what type `null` is.

`CallBack = cdate == DateTime.MinValue ? (DateTime?)null : cdate.Date;`

Comment: "Otherwise the compiler doesn't know what type null is." That's not the problem here. The same expression would have worked if the third operand was a reference type or a nullable type, instead of a non-nullable value type. The problem is that there is no implicit conversion between null and `DateTime`.

Comment: @Jakub Konecki, Please see the code sections L1 & L2 where both are technically equal and i presume csc.exe use same style of compilation for those two sections. Also, if i go with your result then how  DateTime? dt=null works fine (whether you declare it within a method or as a field) ? We don't do any explicit casting here right.

Comment: @Nair the compiler is trying to cast `null` to `DateTime`, not to `DateTime?`. Yes it can cast `null` to `DateTime?`.

Comment: @Nair see my answer, where I explain why the compiler is not able to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use the [`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method which supports nullable types in the first place?

```
DateTime? CallBack = modelValue.Field<DateTime?>("CallBack");
```

But since you actually have a `string` column you need to parse it first:

```
DateTime? CallBack = null;
string callBackDate = modelValue.Field<string>("CallBack");
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(callBackDate))
{
    DateTime cdate;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(callBackDate, out cdate))
        CallBack = cdate;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: It is handy though I it differ from my question. Thanks

Comment: @Nair: I have edited my answer to proide the correct parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
        DateTime aDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime? aNullableDateTime = aDateTime == DateTime.MinValue ? null : new DateTime?(aDateTime.Date);
```

which uses the Nullable(Of T) structure.