# Cannot convert int to nullable int

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullable

In my C# application I want to store null value in an object like:

```
if (txtClass8Year.Text == "")
{
    distributor.Class8YrPassing = null;
}
else
{
    distributor.Class8YrPassing = Convert.ToInt32(txtClass8Year.Text);
}
```

But it is not working when I am trying to write the whole statement in one line:

```
(txtClass8Year.Text == "") ? null : Convert.ToInt32(txtClass8Year.Text);
```

Thanks in advance.

Partha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional operator assignment with Nullable<value> types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/conditional-operator-assignment-with-nullablevalue-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `int` result back to `Nullable<int>` as the `int` in  not the same type as `int?`  and they can't be implicitly casted to and from,so we need to be specific there:

```
distributor.Class8YrPassing = (txtClass8Year.Text == "") 
                               ? null 
                               : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(txtClass8Year.Text);
```

or  alternatively you can make the `null` casted to `int?` that would also work:

```
distributor.Class8YrPassing = (txtClass8Year.Text == "") 
                               ? (int?)null 
                               : Convert.ToInt32(txtClass8Year.Text);
```

As for ternary operator we need to  make sure that in both cases same type is getting  returned, otherwise the compiler would give the error like above.

and a suggestion is that more better  would be to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method instead of checking `""` literal string:

```
distributor.Class8YrPassing = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClass8Year.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtClass8Year.Text)
                               ? null 
                               : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(txtClass8Year.Text);
```

Comment: Nitpicking: casting `null` to `int?` is redundant. `(int?)null` can be simplified to `null`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled On of the return values must make it clear what the return data type of the ternary operator ?: is. Null can be anything. Convert.ToInt32() returns int. Neither implicitely matches int?. Thus you either need to cast the int to an int? or actually descibe what type the null value actually is, hence (int?)null. See Ehsan's two different options above.

Comment: @DeeJ.Doena as I said, I was nitpicking :-).