# C# - There is no implicit conversion between 'int' and <null>

Tags: c#

```
static public string CreatePlaylist(int userId, string playlistName, int playlistImgId)
{
    DataTable playlistTable = Dal.CreatePlaylist(userId, playlistName, playlistImgId);

    Playlist p = new Playlist((int)playlistTable.Rows[0]["UserID"]);

    p.PlaylistName = playlistTable.Rows[0]["Playlist_Name"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)playlistTable.Rows[0]["Playlist_Name"];
    p.PlaylistImg = playlistTable.Rows[0]["Playlist_Img_ID"] == DBNull.Value ? null :  (int)playlistTable.Rows[0]["Playlist_img_ID"];

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(p);

}
```

I get this error :

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and <null>

I found similar questions as this but didn't understand their solution.

Comment: Is `p.PlaylistImg` an `int` or an `int?`? If the first, change the `null` for a `0`, if the second, change `(int)` for `(int?)`

Answer (score 3):

You are casting `playlistTable.Rows[0]["Playlist_img_ID"]` to int, but you have a ternary operation (?:) where you have null as the other operand.

`int` and `null` are not "compatible" for the ternary operation. You should use the nullable `int?` type.

Instead of:

```
p.PlaylistImg = playlistTable.Rows[0]["Playlist_Img_ID"] == DBNull.Value ? null :  (int)playlistTable.Rows[0]["Playlist_img_ID"];
```

Do:

```
p.PlaylistImg = playlistTable.Rows[0]["Playlist_Img_ID"] == DBNull.Value ? null :  (int?)playlistTable.Rows[0]["Playlist_img_ID"];
```

See [Conditional operator assignment with Nullable<value> types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/conditional-operator-assignment-with-nullablevalue-types)

Comment: Since our answers are basically the same, I've deleted mine and upvoted yours. You seen to need the reputation points more than me.

Comment: And what if `PlaylistImg` is declared as `int`? This just provokes another compilation error. It is best to wait until we have enough information and not guess

Comment: @Camilo, you are right. Your comment is more accurate.